# Why does my simple poker program continue to draw the same cards?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, poker

I'm learning Java for my own and i have this problem:

I created a poker program, and every time, both the AI and I draw nothing but the Ace of Spades (5 each) every round. How can I fix this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class poker {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int score1 = 0,score2 = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int[][] previous_cards = new int[0][2];
            int[][] hand1 = generate_hand(previous_cards);
            int[][] sorted1 = sort_hand(hand1);
            System.out.println("Round "+(i+1)+": ");
            System.out.print(" Your hand: ");
            print_hand(sorted1);
            int identify_hand1 = identify_hand(sorted1);
            System.out.print(" ");
            print_identify_hand(identify_hand1);
            System.out.println();
            int[][] hand2 = generate_hand(hand1);
            int[][] sorted2 = sort_hand(hand2);
            System.out.print(" Computer hand: ");
            print_hand(sorted2);
            int identify_hand2 = identify_hand(sorted2);
            System.out.print(" ");
            print_identify_hand(identify_hand2);
            System.out.println();
            int compared = compare_hands(sorted1,sorted2);
            if (compared==-1)
                System.out.println(" You win this round!");
            else if (compared==1)
                System.out.println(" The computer wins this round!");
            else System.out.println("Draw!");
            score1 += (compared<0)?1:0;
            score2 += (compared>0)?1:0;
            System.out.println(" Score: You:"+score1+" - Computer:"+score2);
            input.nextLine();
        }
        if (score1<score2)
            System.out.println("The computer won with: "+score2+"-"+score1+".");
        else if (score1==score2)
            System.out.println("Draw: "+score1+"-"+score2+".");
        else System.out.println("You won with: "+score1+"-"+score2+".");
    }
    public static int[][] generate_hand(int[][] previous_cards) {
        int[][] hand = new int[5][2];
        return hand;
    }
    public static int[] generate_card() {
        int[] card = new int[2];
        card[0] = (int) (Math.random()*13 + 2);
        card[1] = (int) (Math.random()*4 + 1);
        return card;
    }
    public static int compare_2_cards(int[] card1, int[] card2) {
        return 0;
    }
    public static void print_hand(int[][] hand) {
        System.out.print(card_to_String(hand[0])+", ");
        System.out.print(card_to_String(hand[1])+", ");
        System.out.print(card_to_String(hand[2])+", ");
        System.out.print(card_to_String(hand[3])+", ");
        System.out.print(card_to_String(hand[4]));
    }
    public static String card_to_String(int[] c) {
        String card = "";
        if (2<=c[0] && c[0]<=10)
            card += c[0];
        else if (c[0]==11) card += "Jack";
        else if (c[0]==12) card += "Queen";
        else if (c[0]==13) card += "king";
        else card += "Ace";
        card += " of ";
        if (c[1]==1) card += "hearts";
        else if (c[1]==2) card += "diamonds";
        else if (c[1]==2) card += "clubs";
        else card += "spades";
        return card;
    }
    public static int[][] sort_hand(int[][] hand) {
        int[][] sorted = new int[5][2];
        return sorted;
    }
    public static void print_identify_hand(int identify_hand) {
        if (identify_hand==1)
            System.out.print("(straight flush)");
        else if (identify_hand==2)
            System.out.print("(four of a kind)");
        else if (identify_hand==3)
            System.out.print("(full house)");
        else if (identify_hand==3)
            System.out.print("(four of a kind)");
        else if (identify_hand==4)
            System.out.print("(flush)");
        else if (identify_hand==5)
            System.out.print("(straight)");
        else if (identify_hand==6)
            System.out.print("(three of a kind)");
        else if (identify_hand==7)
            System.out.print("(two pairs)");
        else if (identify_hand==8)
            System.out.print("(one pair)");
        else
            System.out.print("(nothing - high hand comparison)");
    }
    public static int compare_hands(int[][] hand1,int[][] hand2) {
// IMPLEMENT: compare 2 cards
        return 1;
    }
    public static int identify_hand(int[][] hand) {
        if (hand[0][1]==hand[1][1] && hand[1][1]==hand[2][1] && hand[2][1]==hand[3][1] && hand[3][1]==hand[4][1] && // compare that they have the same suit
                hand[0][0]+1==hand[1][0] && hand[1][0]+1==hand[2][0] && hand[2][0]+1==hand[3][0] && hand[3][0]+1==hand[4][0]) // compare card numbers
            return 1;
        if (hand[0][0]==hand[1][0] && hand[1][0]==hand[2][0] && hand[2][0]==hand[3][0]) // compare card numbers
            return 2;
        if (hand[1][0]==hand[2][0] && hand[2][0]==hand[3][0] && hand[3][0]==hand[4][0]) // compare card numbers
            return 2;
        return 9;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `new int[0][2]` can never hold data. Your names violate the Java naming conventions. The answer from @Berger lays out the other empty-array issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your `int[][] hand` objects are empty.

The `generate_hand` method returns an empty array, `sort_hand` returns another empty array, the other methods don't alter the array at all.

You end up passing empty (for `int` arrays, that means that each index contains `0`) arrays to `card_to_String`, which then displays the result for `c[0] == 0` and `c[1] == 0`, you got it...this is **Ace of spades**.